Terra package: "PROJ: proj_identify: Cannot find proj.db (GDAL error 1)"
I have been using the fantastic terra package in R for a long time without any problem. However, I reinstalled QGIS recently and since then I get the error "PROJ: proj_identify: Cannot find proj.db (GDAL error 1) " whenever I try to load a simple script to load a vector file:
library(terra)

vect('C:/exampleDirectory/vectorFile.shp')


Warning message:
PROJ: proj_identify: Cannot find proj.db (GDAL error 1)
Since this started happening, I've fully uninstalled R, R Studio, QGIS, and GDAL through OSGEO4W. However the problem persisted. I am running R4.4.1, terra 1.7.78 GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4 and PROJ 9.3.1 in Windows 11. The file is also correctly projected and can be loaded with terra in other computers.
I've read other similar post reporting this error and it seems than repositories other than CRAN can lead to problems. Thus, I removed the package, and installed it again as:
install.packages("terra", type = "binary", repos = "https://cran.r-project.org")

Then I tried using remotes::install_github("rspatial/terra"), after installing RTools, and it  resulted in the same error too.
I was also suspecting  that the sf package could be also problematic, but I tried st_read() for the same file and it worked fine. This also happends if I try older versions of R (tested with 4.4.0).
I've also checked the environment variables, and I report them here in case that could be helpful:
> Sys.getenv('GDAL_DATA')
[1] "C:/Users/grami/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sf/gdal"
> Sys.getenv('PROJ_LIB')
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.38.1\\share\\proj"
> Sys.getenv('PROJ_DATA')
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.38.1\\share\\proj\\proj.db"

How can I solve this issue?

It sounds like the QGIS installation changed your system paths, in particular PROJ_LIB, you can reset it in your scripts using os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r'C:\path\to\GDAL\proj' (probably C:/Users/grami/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sf/gdal/projlib). This would be because your R/GDAL requires a specific version of PROJ_LIB; to take a wild stab it's likely that R is 32bit whereas your QGIS is 64bit, the DLLs are not interchangeable. You should also check GDAL_DATA and GDAL_DRIVER_PATH as they're probably also set to the 64bit QGIS install folder.

Thanks but what you propose didn't work. I managed to find a solution though:
I checked in a  different computer without any preovious installation of R,RStudio or QGIS, and checked what the System environment variables were. All of them were empty.
So after fully uninstalling everything, deleteing the environment variables, deleting any remaining files in other folders (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204017/how-to-uninstall-r-and-rstudio-with-all-packages-settings-and-everything-else) and then installing everything it worked.
